# Chained ruby on rails query to return those that are not nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am querying Active Record and want to chain two queries together.

My issue is that when I want to return those with an attribute that is not nil it doesn't return any records that I know exist:

```rb
user.change_requests.where("action_at = ?", req.action_at).where("cancelled_at != ?", nil)
```

This basically returns an empty array but I'm expecting an array of `change_requests`

Comment: You can use `.where(action_at: req.action_at).where.not(cancelled_at: nil)` If this is not returning anything, then you'd need to share more info, like schema and what records are in the DB

Comment: That works @maxpleaner

Comment: As for why this happens: when comparing to `NULL`, you usually want to use `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL` in SQL. This is strictly different from `= NULL`. Since `NULL` is not equal to anything (not even `NULL` itself), you can't compare it like other values. This is the major difference between `NULL` in SQL and `nil` in Ruby (which mostly is just another object). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL).

Comment: You can also merge those queries into one, something like this: ```user.change_requests.where("action_at  = ? and cancelled_at is not null",  req.action_at)```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Max had the correct answer above in the comments. You can use the ActiveRecord `where.not` syntax when writing sql `NOT`.

From the [ActiveRecord docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#not-conditions):

> **2.4 NOT Conditions**
>
> NOT SQL queries can be built by `where.not`:
>
> `Client.where.not(locked: true)`
>
> In other words, this query can be
>   generated by calling where with no argument, then immediately chain
>   with not passing where conditions. This will generate SQL like this:
>
> `SELECT * FROM clients WHERE (clients.locked != 1)`

For your specific case, the code would look like:

```rb
user.change_requests.where(action_at: req.action_at).where.not(cancelled_at: nil)
```